# Making an array of varchars constrained by a 'references' in SQL

Tags: sql, database, syntax

Imagine

```
CREATE TABLE titles (
  bookTitle varchar(80)
);

CREATE TABLE borrowers (
  name varchar(80), --borrower's name
  checkedOut varchar(80)[] references titles(bookTitle) --list of checked out
);
```

Of course that's not working, but it (hopefully) gets across to you the human reader what I want: I want borrowers to have in one column an array (since more than one title could be checked out at a time) and I want to be sure that only titles that are in the titles table are possible in the borrower's list of checked out titles. What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not introduce a third table and store all the checkedOut for that borrower name in there? Forcing an array into a database field is apples and oranges in my opinion.

```
CREATE TABLE titles (
  bookTitle varchar(80)
);

CREATE TABLE borrowers (
  name varchar(80) --borrower's name
);

CREATE TABLE checkedout (
  name      varchar(80),
  bookTitle varchar(80)
);
```

Comment: Ok, then I'd have checkedout.name have references borrowers(name) and checkedout.bookTitle references titles(bookTitle)

Comment: I agree with BD.  However, I think you should add auto incrementing primary keys and the intersect table should reference those keys, not the names.  I think that will solve your concerns.

Comment: @northpole You are talking about natural vs. surrogate keys. Each of these two approaches has its (dis)advantages, but none is absolutely "better" - that depends on particular circumstances.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - yes, you are absolutely correct and your solution meets both of these.

Answer (score 2):

By storing an array, you are arguably violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and thus the first normal form. Why not make a "proper" relational data model instead?

If a single book can be borrowed by no more than one person at a time, you need an N:1 relationship in your data model, which can be achieved by a simple FOREIGN KEY:

[image]

*(The `TITLE.BORROWED_BY` can be set to NULL if the title is currently not borrowed by anyone.)*

If a single book can be borrowed by multiple persons at a time (whatever that might mean), your model would need an M:N relationship, which can be modeled by an additional "link" table in the middle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't (directly). Relational databases don't have arrays; they have tables (relations) and relationship between them. Consequently, SQL doesn't have the notion of an array.

You could do something like:

```
create table foo
(
  id int not null primary key ,
  col_01 varchar(200) null ,
  col_02 varchar(200) null ,
  ...
  col_nn varchar(200) null ,
)
```

but that is [non-normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms), violating [1st Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form): it has repeating groups.

The schema you want is something like

```
create table book
(
  id          int         not null primary key , -- primary key
  isbn        varchar(32)     null ,
  title varchar(80) not null , -- can't use title as a key as titles are not unique
)

-- you might have multiple copies of the same book
create table book_copy
(
  book_id     int not null ,
  copy_number int not null ,

  primary key ( book_id , copy_number ) ,

  foreign key ( book_id ) references book(id) ,

)

create table customer
(
  id      int         not null primary key ,
  surname varchar(32) not null ,
  name    varchar(32) not null ,
)

create table customer_has_book
(
  customer_id int not null ,
  book_id     int not null ,
  copy_number int not null ,

  primary key ( customer_id , book_id , copy_number ) , -- customer+book+copy number is unique

  unique ( book_id , copy_number ) , -- a given copy may only be borrowed one at a time      

  foreign key ( customer_id ) references customer(id) ,
  foreign key ( book_id , copy_number) references book_copy(book_id,copy_number) ,

)
```